# Format Numeric Number in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, format

I know it has been asked many times and I saw multiple posts about it but it still doesn't work (I checked http://lambert.geek.nz/2009/03/stringformatconverter/).

- I would like to print in textboxes the numbers with spacing and comma (no point but user can still use it as a comma).

For instance : The number printed "12 236,3".
So far I have a converter.
I check and the return value is in good formatting and I call my converter on the textbox, even while debbugging my converter is called but the value printed is "classic" and does not take into account my format.
The converter :

```
public class NumericFieldConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double val = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        string valString = val.ToString();
        string finalString = string.Empty;
        var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
        nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
        finalString = val.ToString("#,0.00", nfi); // "1 234 897.11"
        finalString = finalString.Replace(".", ",");//"1 234 897,11"

        return finalString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object 
parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is my binding in XAML :

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedAvenant.TermeFixe0, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource NumericFieldConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Actually I need to apply the converter to all my textboxes (with a style) but I'll do it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an instance of your converter on your window/usercontrol/...

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:NumericFieldConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

And use this in your TextBox

```
Converter={StaticResource converter},
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but I cannot access Window.Resources I am in a UserControl. What you've written is supposed to be in the xaml, right ?

Comment: Instead of `<Window.Resources>` try `<UserControl.Resources>`

Comment: ok now it is fixed for this part. But now "local" is not defined... I tried to had it in        <UserControl x:Class="Dalkia.MEC.App.MontagesContractuels.GrosSites.Affichage.View.UserControls.UcAvenantGrosSite"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Dalkia.MEC.App.AACommons.CustomControls">

Comment: you have to define local for the namespace where your Converter is included.

Comment: Has the converter the namespace `Dalkia.MEC.App.AACommons.CustomContr‌​ols`? If yes, replace `local` with `uc`, because you already have defined it

Comment: I did : xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dalkia.MEC.App.AACommons.Converters" I used the same path as my CustomControls in the same folder AAComons but still does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Dalkia.MEC.App.AACommons.Converters" It worked for the CustomControls

Comment: I wrote my <UserControl.Resources> right under the <UserControl> where all path are defined. I don't if it show be written here in the xaml.

Comment: It worked without the "Window" part. Thank you. I just edited better the "local" path : xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dalkia.MEC.App.AACommons.Converters">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:NumericFieldConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>                                                                            Now I have to take care of my convertback . Thank you

Comment: How can I apply my converter on all my textbox as a style ? <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="??????" Value="???"/>

Comment: I think that is a different question (and not an easy one). Please accept this as the answer, if it is answering your question, and write a new one for the problem with the style.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.NumericInput) library supports formatting.

Sample:

```
<numeric:DoubleBox Culture="sv-se"
                   StringFormat="#,0.00"
                   Value="{Binding Value}" />
```